# Does probability change if I randomly choose a subset

Tags: probability

I have a set of $1000$ different pictures. I will pick 10 pictures at random, removing the chosen ones from the set. The probability of the first pick will be $\frac{1}{1000}$, the second one $\frac{1}{999}$ and so on.

In my second scenario I will have a set of $1000$ different pictures again. I will pick a random number between $1$ and $10$, let's say $3$ (random). I will now choose $10$ random pictures again, but only out of every $3$rd. So my set out of what I can pick will now be $3$rd, $6$th, $9$th, $12$th, ...

Is the probability of choosing any single picture now different from the first scenario? Is it more unlikely for any picture to get picked in the second scenario?

My guess is no, since although the set is smaller to pick from it is still based on picking a random number.

Comment: What do you mean by "The probability of the first pick will be $\frac{1}{1000}$?"

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think pictures with "large prime numbers" (eg. 997) seem far less likely to be picked. Since 997 is not divisible $2,3,4...10$, the only way to pick the 997th picture as first is if your random number is $1$.

Comment: For the second scenario you mean you will do 30 picks in total and only keep those that are 0 mod 3?

Comment: @5xum I am wondering that too. If we take it at face value, the question doesn't make sense, because the sum of probabilities is not equal to 1

Comment: @5xum I will just choose 10 pictures randomly in no particular order. Doesn't this make the probability 1/1000 to choose any picture out of 1000?

Comment: @Qise For the second scenario I'm again just picking 10 pictures, but only the 3rd, 6th, 9th, out of (an ordered) set.

Comment: @jadu3 then clearly it's not the same thing because you cannot pick any card with an id which is a prime number greater than 11. Or I still don't get it

Answer (score 0):

The key is actually to understand that in your second suggestion you have assumed a **specific** order on the images.
Both definitions would be equal if you assume some random permutation $\sigma$ on $\{1,...,1000\}$ before starting your process.

On the first you have no order hence the chances are $\frac{1* ... *10}{1000^{10}}$. In your second method you pick a random permutation as one out of $1000!$ options, and then choose a random number $1/10$ and only then you pick the photos.
This would even out when you look at the **mean** chance of picking any specific one.

Comment: Yes that is true the second scenario implies some specific order (altough the order is at random, but does not change after each pick).

Answer (score 0):

In the first scenario the probability of a specific picture being among the 10 picked pictures will be the same regardsles of which picture you select as the "specific" picture. In other words, if you say "my specific picture is number 11" the probability will be exactly the same as if you say "my specific picture is number 359".

In the second scenario it matters a lot which picture number you select as the specific picture.

Take picture number 11 as example. Only the random number 1 will leave picture number 11 in the reduced set of pictures from where you'll pick 10 random pictures. For all other random numbers picture 11 will not be part of the reduced set and consequently can't end up in the final set of 10 pictures.

When the random number is 1 the scenario is exactly the same as the first scenario so the probability for picture 11 is the same as the first scenario. However because the probability of getting random number 1 is 1 out of 10 and because all other random numbers can't lead to picture number 11, the probability of picking picture number 11 is 10 times less in scenario 2 than scenario 1.

Exactly the same applies for picture number 1. It also applies for all picture numbers being primes above 10.